# How to set headers in https request in mule

Tags: java, rest, https, mule, mule-esb

I am using mule 3.3.2. I want to set few headers in https request. In http:outbound-endpoint I use http:request-builder to add headers. But it doesn't work in https:outbound-endpoint.

Any help would beappreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To add headers to https request, set-property tag works.